# How can I remove all text after a newline character in bash?

Tags: bash

Suppose I have a Bash object $TEST defined like this:

```
> TEST=`echo -e "hello\\nworld"`
> echo $TEST 
hello 
world
```

Using just echo, how do I output 'hello' from $TEST? How do I output 'world' from TEST? (no other commands allowed). I have trouble getting it to recognize the newline character.

Comment: Err... "no other commands allowed"? Is this homework of some kind?

Comment: Actually no, I just wanted to rule out other solutions that use a combination of commands (like 'head') with pipes, for my own learning benefit.

Comment: You might want to add a line to that end to future questions. Homework questions attract a different kind of answer. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `bash` parameter expansion:

```
$ echo "$TEST"
hello
world

$ echo "${TEST%$'\n'*}"
hello

$ echo "${TEST#*$'\n'}"
world
```

Answer (score 0):

The built-in `read` command can extract one line at a time.

```
$ { IFS= read -r line1; IFS= read -r line2; } <<< "$TEST"
$ echo "$line1"
hello
$ echo "$line2"
world
```